# How to avoid overwrite and keep both files in the folder via excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I created a code to copy file by the partial names which are included in the active workbook and when it is done that cell will be colored.

I used "Boolean" option to overwrite the files before but **now I need to keep both files in the Target Folder if same file with same name exists in the Target Folder.** How do I solve this?

```
Sub Copy_by_keyword()
    Dim sSrcFolder As String
    Dim sTgtFolder As String
    Dim sFilename As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim rPatterns As Range
    Dim bBad As Boolean

    sSrcFolder = ("C:\Personal\Reports")
    sTgtFolder = ("D:\VBA\Trade\")

    Set rPatterns = ActiveSheet.Range("M10:M100").SpecialCells(xlConstants)
    For Each c In rPatterns
        sFilename = Dir(sSrcFolder & "*" & c.Text & "*")
        If sFilename = "" Then
            c.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            bBad = False  'I tried to use this as False but nothing happens'
        Else
            While sFilename <> ""
                FileCopy sSrcFolder & sFilename, sTgtFolder & sFilename
                sFilename = Dir()
                c.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Wend
        End If
    Next c
    If bBad Then MsgBox "Files not found"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep both files then check if it exists and rename it before copy.
For check if it exists you can use the following snippet.

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim filepath As String
filepath = "yourfilepath"

While fso.FileExists(filepath)
'rename it
Wend
```

For using the `FileSystemObject` you have to set a reference on `Windwos Script Host Object Model`

**EDIT**: To answer your comment:
You can check if exists and then open a message box:

```
If MsgBox("Override", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
End If
```

Comment: Actually what I need is to keep both files in the target folder when same filename exists like when we copy manually windows asks to keep both files in the directory.Is it possible to be done via vba macro??

Comment: I would really appreciate your assistance but unfortunately there were some files which name change according to the time and remaining parts of the file name is same.it seems to me In a situation like that opening a message box would not be the best solution.isnt it?

Comment: So if it is no option for you to use a message box then use the other method. Check if the file exists and if so generate another name.